# qml virtual keyboard digits only

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am looking at the basic QML example for the virtual keyboard with the `Qt 5.9` installation. A textfield which only takes digits can be instantiated as follows:

```
TextField {
    id: digitsField
    width: parent.width
    previewText: "Digits only field"
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
    enterKeyAction: EnterKeyAction.Next
    onEnterKeyClicked: textArea.focus = true
}
```

The issue is that I can also enter spaces and period `.` through the virtual keyboard (I am not sure if the exact characters depend on the locale). I am not sure why those are allowed as they are not digits. Is it possible to actually have it digits only?

Comment: Error using Your code: `Cannot assign to non-existent property "onEnterKeyClicked"` - what exact code should be to show numeric keyboard? In my case it shows literal characters keyboard initially, and on any key press in text input - starts to show numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain a more fine grained control by using [`inputMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#inputMask-prop) or [`validator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#validator-prop) as follows:

```
inputMask: "000000" // Allows up to 6 digits, i.e. 1 digit for each 0
```

or

```
validator: IntValidator {} // Allows any integer
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the job!